# Using eSata on external hard drive

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, esata, firewire

I have a Lacie D2 Quadra that I have been using through firewire 800. Mac pros at school have an eSata hookup, but my HD will not show up when I try to use it this way. I have assumed the drive is not hotswappable and turned the comp on after plugging in the drive. 
Am I missing something about eSata here?

Comment: Is the eSATA controller/port enabled? Not sure it can be enabled/disabled on Macs like it can on most PC motherboards.

Comment: Not sure...but I'm assuming that if the school went through all the trouble of installing the ports and cables they would enable us to use it! I could be wrong though. :P 
So there's nothing wrong with what I'm doing though?

Comment: Not that I can find by reading your question. eSata doesn't have a power connection, so do you have the harddisk plugged in a power supply?

Comment: Are you asking if I have the Lacie plugged into a power supply? If so, then yes, the drive will not work without it.

Comment: @kato I have an external that can do usb and esata. I went back to usb because id have to restart(sometimes) multiple times for it to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your eSata drive is, like mine, connected ultimately to the 'spare' eSata port on earlier MacPros, its not hot-swappable so won't be picked up except after reboot. But it should 'just work' - no config or enabling is usually required. Have you tried it with a more than one of your school MacPros?

For what its worth, you [are not alone](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/feedback/mac_pro_ext_sata_case_kit.html) and, like this guy, you might even get some help from Lacie with this.